# MySQL: Get AUTO_INCREAMENTED sequence number after Insert?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, sql-insert, mysql-insert-id

I've MySQL Table with Primary key as AUTO_INCREAMENTED (UNSIGNED INT) as sequence number. 
Every Time I insert new row in this table, I want to give acknowledgement to the user showing inserted AUTO_INCREAMENTED UNSIGNED INT.

Currently after inserting row, I’m executing SELECT Query to get last inserted row. 
Is there any smarter way to get inserted value, immediately after INSERT (without SELECT) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `mysql_insert_id()`

```
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

Refer [**THIS**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) for more about `mysql_insert_id()`

And Try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

In `mysqli_*` it will be like

```
echo mysqli_insert_id();
```

Comment: I don't get why you say to use `mysql_insert_id` and then go on to say that `ext/mysql` is deprecated. Just recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) functions for this.

Comment: @Mike I suggested him to not use mysql_* functions for the future purpose.

Comment: I don't see anywhere he says he's using ext/mysql.

Comment: That's why I suggested mysqli_* and PDO...and given solution in mysqli_* also

Comment: Thanks Gautam. It's working perfectly.  I'm working on migrating to MySQLI.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Or [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) in PHP scripts. You can also use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php) instead of mysqli

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) that can be used for that.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(32));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1(name) VALUES ("John Doe");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.24 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | John Doe |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: OP said specifically "without SELECT"

Comment: I assume that he meant that he didn't want to use a select to fetch the last row from the table.